# UINavigationControllers: How to pass value to higher (parent?) controller in stack?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegation

I have SendingController which push to nav stack SendingDeatilsController (which one has a TableView). User should should pick in TableView one row (it checked by Checkmark) and I would like to pass the value of this row (let it will NSString object) to the SendingController.

How can I realize this behaviour in my application?  And is SendingController parent for SendingDetailController (attribute parentController of SDC refers to SC) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement this behaviour, pass the `SendingDetailController` a reference to the previous view controller. This way the detail view controller can send a message to the previous one on the stack.

In your `SendingDetailController` define a weak reference :

```
// in .h
SendingController *sendingController;
@property(assign) SendingController *sendingController;

// in .m
@synthesize sendingController;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // retrieve the string and send the message
    [sendingController didSelectString:theString];
}
```

Now before pushing the `SendingDetailController` on the stack don't forget to set its `sendingController` property.

```
// .m
// where you push the vc
if(!sendingDetailController) {
    sendingDetailController = [[SendingDetailController alloc]
                               initWithNibName:@"TheNIBName"
                                        bundle:nil];
    sendingDetailController.sendingController = self;
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sendingDetailController
                                     animated:YES];
```

and write the method that will recieve the string.

```
-(void)didSelectString:(NSString *)aString {
    // do anything with string
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Should I release sendingController property in dealloc of SendingDetailController ??

Comment: @LIAL - no, as you can see in the property definition, the value is just assigned, not retained. this is a weak reference.

Answer (score 0):

For easy asynchronous communication between different UIViewControllers, you may want to look at [NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There are plenty tutorials on the web and some good answers here at SO that can show you how to do that exactly.