# Need assistance regarding passing data from child to parent in UINavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In UINavigationController this is child controller

```
.h

@protocol childProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)childMethod:(NSArray*)params;

@end

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<childProtocol>childDelegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) parentVC *pVC;
```

---

```
.m 

if([self.childDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(childMethod:)]) {

    [self.childDelegate performSelector:@selector(childMethod:) withObject:self.arry];    

}
```

This is my parent controller

```
.m

-(void)childMethod:(NSArray *)params {
    // some work 
}

...

 childVC *cVC = [[childVC alloc]init];
    cVC.pVC = self;
```

But childMethod: is not getting called so I searched on internet and got this post
[UINavigationControllers: How to pass value to higher (parent?) controller in stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800226/uinavigationcontrollers-how-to-pass-value-to-higher-parent-controller-in-sta)

I tried to create a weak reference but dont know how to use to make delegate pass data from child to parent?

Comment: Show us how you assigned the delegate to your parent view controller.

Comment: @Zen ParentViewController<abcProtocol, UITextFieldDelegate, childProtocol>

Comment: What I meant was how is the pVC property is conforming to the `childDelegate`. i.e. if there is something like `self.childDelegate = self.pVC;` or anything like that telling the `pVC` that it has to act when the `childDelegate` is revoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Check the sample project attached

**ParentViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController

- (void)passData:(NSString *)strText;

@end
```

**ParentViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnGoToSecondView:(id)sender {
    ChildViewController *secondVC = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondVC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)passData:(NSString *)strText {
    NSLog(@"Data Passed = %@",strText);
}
```

**ChildViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ParentViewController.h"

@class ParentViewController;

@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, assign) ParentViewController *delegate;

@end
```

**ChildViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnPassDataBack:(id)sender {
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(passData:)]) {
        [self.delegate passData:@"Hello"];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilb0mpi0ia2fd9f/DelegateExample.zip)

Comment: @S.J Please check the sample attached.

Comment: Please can you tell how it is possible in uinavigationcontroller

Comment: @S.J its the same with UINavigationViewController

Comment: so child in stack do not need any weak or strong reference of parent in uinavigationcontroller?

Comment: @S.J weak reference will do.

Comment: @S.J If you find this answer correct then please "up-vote" or "accept" the answer. Thanks

Comment: @S.J I dont think weak/strong reference will be issue. Did you checkout the sample code.?

Answer (score 2):

This is child controller.h

```
@protocol childProtocol <NSObject>
    -(void)childMethod:(NSArray*)params;

@end

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<childProtocol>childDelegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) parentVC *pVC;
```

.m

```
if([self.childDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(childMethod:)]) {

    [self.childDelegate performSelector:@selector(childMethod:) withObject:self.arry];    

}
```

This is my parent controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ChildController.h"


@interface perentController : UIViewController < childProtocol >
```

.m

```
- (void)childMethod:(NSArray *)params {
        // some work 
}
```

**EDITED :**

And Dont Forget to add `childViewOBJ.childDelegate = self;` at the time of create `ChildViewController's` object. such like,

```
childVC *cVC = [[childVC alloc]init];
cVC.childDelegate = self;
cVC.pVC = self;
[self presentModalViewController:cVC animated:YES];
```

For More information about [How to create/use of Protocol.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)

Comment: why you copy paste my question as answer, if you are thing that I didnt did this  UIViewController < childProtocol > so thats wrong I have already implemented this.

Comment: @S.J- First check it, it is not totally same as your question.. i just want to help you, nothing any more okay.... :)

Comment: please check my question again I corrected my copy paste mistake.

Comment: @S.J just follow my edited answer :) and if still then any problem then follo link that i added to my answer :)

Comment: I know how to use delegates and in my init method I have already don this self.cVC = [[childVC alloc]init];
        self.cVC.childDelegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not checking for the same selector as you declared in your protocol declaration so it won't respond to that. You declared the method `childMethod:` whereas you are checking if your childDelegate responds to `myMethod:` selector which does not so it won't go into the if condition.

Also the parent view controller is missing the implementation the method `childMethod:` in its .m. Implement that in your parent view controller or it will crash because of not finding the exact selector definition.

Since you are using a `UINavigationController`, the parent view controller won't be lost till the child view controller exist so the `childDelegate` property must not be strong unless you intend to hold onto your delegate in child view controller for some reason.

Comment: sorry copy paste mistake, in my code I am calling the correct selector.